# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in /app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, node-modules

I'm running the command `docker run globoapp/latest` and it's showing me

```
> globoapp@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start 

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is 
not defined by "exports" in /app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:429:9)      
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:683:3)     
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31) 
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)     
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.1.0
```

So I downgraded my node to v16.13.0 and I uninstall & install node modules and it didn't work
So I created the app again and tried still not working

Answer (score 1):

I executed `npm update`, which triggered a re-creation/fix of the package-lock.json:

```
➜ npm update
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
...
```

After that I started the app again and worked fine.

Comment: worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Right. An update to the latest version of "react-scripts" is required! Previous "react-scripts" version was `4.0.3` and I've updated to `5.0.0`. Node version is `17.0.1`.